# Ember Object Property definition

Tags: ember.js

Here's my question:

I have a list of books, with the `isAvailable` boolean property

I would like to create a property called `availability`, which will return "product available" if `isAvailable`, and I'd like to use this property in an `#each`statement

```
availability: function () {
    if (this.get('isAvailable'))
        return "book available";
    else
        return "book not available";
    }.property()


{{#each book in arrangedContent}}
    {{availability}}
{{/each}}
```

In which object must I define my new property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend your books model:

```
var model;

model = DS.Model.extend({
  isAvailable: DS.attr('boolean'), // This is what you already have

  availability: function() {
    if (this.get('isAvailable')) {
      return 'book available';
    } else {
      return 'book not available';
    }
  }.property('isAvailable')


});

export default model;
```

In your template you have to write book.availability...